# Crash report.. [UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, crash

I have been seeing the below crash in my app through testflight. I am not understanding where and how this crash happens. I have multiple UITableViewControllers in my app ( around 10 ), hence not really sure which piece of code to paste here. Any help will be really appreciated. I have already researched lots of SO questions, but I havent been able to nail down a cause.

```
0 Anyvan 0x0019052e testflight_backtrace + 382
1 Anyvan 0x0019117c TFSignalHandler + 264
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b1b9e92 _sigtramp + 42
3 UIKit 0x34e6654c -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal)   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
4 UIKit 0x34e4b312 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1310
5 UIKit 0x34e627ce -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 206
6 UIKit 0x34e1e802 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 258
7 QuartzCore 0x34bc8d8a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 214
8 QuartzCore 0x34bc8928 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 460
9 QuartzCore 0x34bc985c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 16
10 QuartzCore 0x34bc9242 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 238
11 QuartzCore 0x34bc9050 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 316
12 UIKit 0x34e248ea _afterCACommitHandler + 126
13 CoreFoundation 0x32fe86cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
14 CoreFoundation 0x32fe69c0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
15 CoreFoundation 0x32fe6d16 __CFRunLoopRun + 742
16 CoreFoundation 0x32f59ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
17 CoreFoundation 0x32f59d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18 GraphicsServices 0x36b322ea GSEventRunModal + 74
19 UIKit 0x34e6f300 UIApplicationMain + 1120
20 Anyvan 0x000e4c14 main (main.m:17)
21 Anyvan 0x000e4bb7 start + 39
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it happens when I scroll table and dealloc viewcontroller (which has array data for table)
We might need to keep viewcontroller alive until view that contain table disappear

Comment: How can you do that? Got same issue only when there is more cells that my current table view can show.

Comment: This is old question and I think this will not happen in ARC project
Anyways, if you still use non-ARC you might try to retain that uiviewcontroller (do not destroy it until you go to that view again)
you might store that viewcontroller pointer in some singleton http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm actually working on an ARC project. Don't know really why, but when I clean my database, it force reloadData in the tableView, that cause the crash for me, I had to trick it when rebuilding cell. I can't avoid that in any other ways I found. Datasource was the cause, not the current viewController.

Comment: Hey @Ben I seem to have the same exact issue, how did you figure it out?

Comment: @GabrielCartier I added a flag when I flush the database, then I check the state of the flag when creating cells. If it has been flushed, then I'm sure I shouldn't display anything. But I never came back to this issue to find another workaround. Hope it can help you.